# ring homorphism from $\mathbb{Z+Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z+Z}$

Tags: ring-theory

> Determine all the ring homorphisms from $\mathbb{Z+Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z+Z}$

This homorphism can be determined by $f((0,1))$ and $f((1,0))$ then how to proceed further?

This question is discussed here [Determine all ring homomorphism from$ \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$into $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2359305/809050)

But I am not understanding.

Comment: Is it $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}^2$?

Comment: What are you not understanding?

Comment: How to determine $f(0,1)$, $f(1,0)$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ both square to themselves: $$(1,0)(1,0)=(1,0),\qquad (0,1)(0,1)=(0,1).$$  Thus they must map to elements of the form: $(x,y)$ with $$(x,y)=(x,y)(x,y)=(x^2,y^2).$$  Thus $x^2=x$ and $y^2=y$ so $x,y\in\{0,1\}.$

That gives $16$ possibilities, with each of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ mapping to one of $(0,1),(1,0), (1,1), (0,0)$.

However a ring homomorphism must map $(1,1)$ to $(1,1)$.  Thus you are left with $4$ ring homomorphisms:
$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}(1,0)\mapsto (0,0), && (1,0)\mapsto (0,1),&&(1,0)\mapsto (1,0),&&(1,0)\mapsto (1,1).\\
(0,1)\mapsto (1,1) && (0,1)\mapsto (1,0)&&(0,1)\mapsto (0,1)&&(0,1)\mapsto (0,0)
\end{array}$$

Note these correspond to the identity, swapping the factors, and projecting the first or second factor onto the diagonal.

Answer (score -1):

Well, $f(a,b) = a\cdot f(1,0) + b\cdot f(0,1)$, where $f(1,0), f(0,1)\in{\Bbb Z}^2$ are fixed.

Comment: How to determine $f(0,1)$, $f(1,0)$

Comment: These are the two images which have to be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{Hom}{Hom}$
Let $A, B, C$ be abelian groups.  Let $A \oplus B$ be the abelian group whose underlying set is $A \times B$ with the group operation $(a,b)+(a',b') = (a+a',b+b')$.  Let $\Hom(A,B)$ be the set of homomorphisms from $A$ to $B$.  These three facts should help you:

- There is a natural bijection of sets $\Hom(A \oplus B, C) \rightarrow \Hom(A,C) \times \Hom(B,C)$.  Explicitly, if $f: A \oplus B \rightarrow C$ is a homomorphism, define the homomorphisms $g: A \rightarrow C$ and $h: B \rightarrow C$ by

$$g(a) = f(a,0)$$

$$h(b) = f(0,b).$$
Then that bijection is defined by sending $f$ to the pair $(g,h)$.

- There is a bijection of sets $\Hom(A, B \oplus C) \rightarrow \Hom(A,B) \times \Hom(A,C)$. This can be reasoned out similarly to the last fact.
- For every abelian group $A$, there is a natural bijection of sets $\Hom(\mathbb Z, A) \rightarrow A$ by sending $f$ to $f(1)$.

You can put these three facts together to solve the problem essentially in one line.

The first two facts can be stated in a way that probably won't make sense to you now, but will later if you learn some category theory.  Namely, the direct sum $A \oplus B$ is both a coproduct and a product in the category of abelian groups.